# Efficiently Load Large Amounts of Data into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to make this more efficient? Assuming `TimeStart = 0` and `TimeEnd = 9,000,000` id have a very very long range to iterate over and load into my dataframe. I was reading about making a dictionary of the data and then loading the dict in all at once into the dataframe. I can't really wrap my head around how to make that work with what I am doing. The code is currently apending each row to the dataframe which is very very inefficient.

```
for i in range(TimeStart,TimeEnd,50):
    chValue = objChannel.getInterpolatedValue(i)
    time = i/10000
    df = df.append({'Time': time, 'Speed': chValue} , ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What is `objChannel.getInterpolatedValue`

Comment: @Yo_Chris stuff on my end. For the sake of the question `chValue` can be an arbitrary value.

Comment: for starters your just appending a value unto it self, your not holding it in any sort of container?

Comment: @Datanovice not using any container. Currently appending to the dataframe every iteration.

Comment: `df = df.append(...)` is O(N^2), since your are copying `i-1` rows at `i`th iteration. Try creating a dict of lists first, and pass it to a dataframe later.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem that's why I am asking the question, I don't understand how to do that..

Comment: Repeatedly appending to DataFrames destroys performance, try building an intermediate/temporary data structure, and later create the entire DF at once. Can you show an example of the expected output? I'm having a tough time following what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension will certainly be faster:

```
TimeStart = 0
TimeEnd = 100000

l = [[i/10000, objChannel.getInterpolatedValue(i)] for i in range(TimeStart,TimeEnd,50)]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Time', 'Speed'])


# %%timeit 1.99 ms ± 156 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Setting `TimeEnd` to 9000000 runs in 125 ms ± 6.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) when I just return `i` instead of `objChannel.getInterpolatedValue(i)`. For example, `l = [[i/10000, i] for i in range(TimeStart,TimeEnd,50)]`